# What does the Boolean returned by SignedXml.CheckSignature actually represent?

Tags: c#, ws-security, signedxml

When `SignedXml.CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)` returns `true` (or `false`), what exactly does this represent does this represent?

Does this mean that the `Signature` is valid; or that whatever `Signature` object you created matches when you tried to create the `Signature` again?

Comment: I feel compelled to point you to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148731%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SignedXml.CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)` does three checks:

1. Checks that the hash of the `SignedInfo` in the signature is signed by the supplied key. This ensure that the data is from a sender with the corresponding public key.
2. Checks that the hash in the `SignedInfo` is correct. This ensures that the contents of the `Signature` block has not been tampered with.
3. Checks that the digest of all references are correct, after applying the listed transforms. This ensure that the data protected by the signature is not tampered with.

Note that you at this point has no idea what data is actually signed - it might be only parts of the document. Before trusting data, you also have to [validate the signatures](https://coding.abel.nu/2015/12/xml-signatures-and-references/).